# responsive background with resizable div content

Tags: html, css

I have made an example in [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/2VB3yVbzHNdyGrWKkwbl?p=preview) to better explain my problem. My issue is when I'm playing with window size, background is responsive and everything is good, but if I extend content more then window size and then scroll down, I see how background color repeats. I've tried a lot of ways to resolve this problem but result is always similar. I appreciate if somebody could help me to resolve this issue.

My css code:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {

    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;

    background: rgba(183,222,237,1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(183,222,237,1) 0%, rgba(33,180,226,0.64) 51%, rgba(183,222,237,0.3) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(183,222,237,1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(33,180,226,0.64)), color-stop(100%, rgba(183,222,237,0.3))) fixed;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(183,222,237,1) 0%, rgba(33,180,226,0.64) 51%, rgba(183,222,237,0.3) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(183,222,237,1) 0%, rgba(33,180,226,0.64) 51%, rgba(183,222,237,0.3) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(183,222,237,1) 0%, rgba(33,180,226,0.64) 51%, rgba(183,222,237,0.3) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(183,222,237,1) 0%, rgba(33,180,226,0.64) 51%, rgba(183,222,237,0.3) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b7deed', endColorstr='#b7deed', GradientType=0 );
}
.child-grid {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    padding:10px;
    resize:vertical;
    overflow:visible;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /* own property*/
    /*width: 95%;*/
    height: 300px;
    min-height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to the body tag:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/dvf7cm5RNTcHb8241vyD?p=preview)

That should work

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have to add the following line **after** the background-properties:

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

Comment: but it doesn't make background responsive, instead of repeated background I see only white color now

Comment: So what exactly is the result you would like to see? From your post it appeared the problem was that the background repeats

Comment: I would like to see extended background, for example if you resize div more than window screen, background has to resize either and instead of white or repeat color, I want to see full covered background